# How to Retrieve data from selected ListBox?

Tags: c#

In C#.Net ,I'm trying to retrieve data from selected ListBox.

Eg. First I displayed many data in ListBox that retrieved from MSSQL 2008 Database.
    When i select single data from that listbox , i want to show that selected data into textbox...
How can i do that?
I need yours answers because i'm just beginner ,
Please answer me if you know..
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on how you stored your data into the list. Is that simple string or some complex object, is either case you can cast the selected item to it's appropriate type.
For example.
If your list box contains only string type items, you will get the selected item by

```
string value=(string) this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

If your listbox contains other Complex type, you will get the selected item by

```
SomeComplexObject value=(SomeComplexObject) this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Or if you have binded listbox to some sort of datatable or dataset. 
you can get the value of the selected item using

```
string value=listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

So now,
When listbox selected index changed. you can set textbox value using.
First, subscribe to listbox index changed event

```
 this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged+=new EventHandler(changed);
```

And your handler.

```
 private void changed(object sender,EventArgs args)
        {
            //set your text box text property here
            //with the code provided earlier
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Trap the `ListBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` event, for example you can do,

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); //let textBox1 be your TextBox name and listBox1 be your ListBox name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...i also want to know which event to select ListBox..SelectedIndexChanged (or) SelectedValueChanged....
What's is the different between that two?

Comment: Thanks for answer...i also want to know which event to select ListBox..SelectedIndexChanged (or) SelectedValueChanged....
What's is the different between that two?
Please answer me .....Thanks again

Comment: Yes..your answer right...But when i selected data from listbox and display that data in textbox , there is only display " System.Data.DataRowView " Word...Data aren't show....

Comment: Try DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem; textBox1.Text = drv.Row["MyColumn"].ToString();//replace MyColumn with your column name

Comment: Thanks you answer my question...Now i like stackoverflow alot....and all of you guys....

Comment: Accept whatever answer you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET use below code:

```
var selectedValue = listBoxObj.SelectedItem.value;
```